# Subtract List in grails with repeating elements

Tags: java, list, grails

I want to subtract lists with repeating elements. For example:

```
List<String> list1 = ['APPROVE', 'APPROVE', 'CARVEOUT', 'DENY', 'CARVEOUT'];
List<String> list2 = ['APPROVE', 'CARVEOUT', 'DENY', 'APPROVE']
// i tried
List<String> final = list1-list2;
```

The answer I want is ['CARVEOUT']
This method eleminates the commom elements hence I am getting an Empty list. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Answer should be `['CARVEOUT']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[.remove(Object o)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-)** method which deletes the first occurrence of the object.

```
List<String> list1 =new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"APPROVE", "APPROVE", "CARVEOUT", "DENY", "CARVEOUT"}));
List<String> list2 =new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"APPROVE", "APPROVE", "CARVEOUT", "DENY"}));

for(String str:list2)
    list1.remove(new String(str));

System.out.println(list1);
```

Gives Output :

```
[CARVEOUT]
```

Comment: Yes bro thats exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [list1.removeAll(list2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) to remove all `list2` elements from `list1`. But, note that `removeAll()` method **removes ALL matching** (with `equals`) elements in the `list1`.

So, in your case, if you wanted to remove the elements based on the number of occurrences of `list2`, you can use `remove()` as shown below:

```
list2.stream().forEach(element -> list1.remove(element));
```

Comment: I tried that in groovy console. But it returns Boolean value. Am i missing something here?

Comment: removeAll returns boolean rather the output contents will be in list1

Comment: It makes change in the original `list`.

Comment: well yea!! but it returned an empty list

Comment: yes, because all elements from `'list2` are matching with `list1`

Comment: can't i have remaining element CARVEOUT form list1 as my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support overloading operators , so you should instead use.

`list1.removeAll(list2);`